# JQuery to add <body> class, need a little more help

Tags: javascript, jquery, theming

I have this snippet of code to parse the URL and add a class to the `<body>`tag of my HTML page.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var pathSlashesReplaced = pathname.replace(/\//g, " ");
var pathSlashesReplacedNoFirstDash = pathSlashesReplaced.replace(" ","");
var newClass = pathSlashesReplacedNoFirstDash.replace(/(\.[\s\S]+)/ig, "");

$("body").attr("class",newClass);
if ( $("body").attr("class") == "")
{
$("body").addClass("class");
}
```

The issue I am having is that it deletes existing body classes already there. Instead, I would like to append to whatever body classes exist and not overwrite.

Comment: What's wrong with `$('body').addClass(newClass)` or `$('body')[0].className += ' '+newClass` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `addClass` instead of `attr('class', newClass)`. The `addClass` also accepts a white-space separated list of class names, and correctly adds them.

```
$("body").addClass(newClass);
if ( $("body").attr("class") == "") // Makes no sense, since you have previously 
{                                   // added `newClass`
    $("body").addClass("class");
}
```

For documentation on `addClass`, see http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$("body").addClass(newClass);
```

instead of

```
$("body").attr("class",newClass);
```

This is a setter: `$("body").attr("class",newClass);` which sets the class to the newClass and does not append it.

Answer (score 2):

`.attr("class", newClass)` is removing all existing classes. You should be using `.addClass()` instead:

```
$("body").addClass(newClass);
```

In addition, since you've just added a class to `body`, the code below will always be false:

```
if ( $("body").attr("class") == "") { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use addClass function instead - http://api.jquery.com/addClass/